# What sort order does Linux use?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

My Bash script is running things in a folder, in alphanumerical order. But it turns out it's not the same order as the one I have in my Mac OS folder. So now I'm wondering what sorting order Linux uses, and can it be changed? Can I change it for my Bash script only? Say I want to run a video player in a Bash script, running all videos in a folder in alphanumerical order, can I specify in the script what alphanumerical order it should be?

Comment: The sort order depends on the locale, which can be set with the environment variable `LC_ALL`.

Comment: Please show some examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sort order for many commands (incl. `bash` glob, `ls`, `sort`) is based on your current locale settings.

You can *force* the collation by setting the `LC_COLLATE` environment variable. Setting it to *C* will perform a comparison on *byte* values.

On my system (*en_US.utf8*):

```
sh$ touch eleve
sh$ touch élève
sh$ touch Eleve 
sh$ touch Élève
sh$ touch äkta
sh$ touch österreich

sh$ ls
äkta  eleve  Eleve  élève  Élève  österreich  pommes

sh$ LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.utf8 ls
äkta  eleve  Eleve  élève  Élève  österreich  pommes

sh$ LC_COLLATE=sv_SE.utf8 ls
eleve  Eleve  élève  Élève  pommes  äkta  österreich

sh$ LC_COLLATE=C ls
Eleve  eleve  pommes  Élève  äkta  élève  österreich
```

Comment: Can I permanently change this? Where is the LC_COLLATE located?

Comment: @Paolo, add it to your ~/.bash_profile (or ~/.profile if you use that): `export LC_COLLATE=C` (or whatever